# How to get sum of values from a dictionary and append them to a new dictionary in python

Tags: json, python-3.x, dictionary, sum, jsondecoder

I have a dictionary that has string values. I would like to take these values and add all of them from the dictionary, then make a new dictionary that shows the sum of the values and append it to the existing dictionary.

Existing JSON:

```
{"id": "id-001", "id name": "city 1", "Level EMT": "software engineer", "days total": "100", "days total 2": "111", "days total 3": "56", "days total 4": "158", "days total": "48", "days total 5": "37", "days total 6": "188", "days total": "121", "date": "04/06/2022 00:00:00 AM"}
```

I would like for it to look like this afterwards:

```
{"Total Days": 819}{"id": "id-001", "id name": "city 1", "Level EMT": "softwar engineer", "hours total": "100", "days total 2": "111", "days total 3": "56", "days total 4": "158", "": "48", "days total 5": "37", "days total 6": "188", "days total": "121", "date": "04/06/2022 00:00:00 AM"}
```

The only thing that is different is that the new dictionary is being added in front of the existing one with the sum of all the values from it. The total is 819.

I have my code below that uses a data hook to go to the function from json.loads.

def data_hook(json_dict):

```
totalDays = {"Total Days": ""}
totalHoursIncurredField = dict(totalHoursIncurred, **json_dict)

for(key, value) in json_dict.items():

    if key == "days total":
        totalHoursIncurredField = dict(totalHoursIncurred, **json_dict)
        
        for k, v in totalHoursIncurredField.items():
            sumOfValues = sum(int((json_dict.values())))
            print(sumOfValues)

return json_dict
```

Here is the json.loads with the data hook:

```
 json_doc = json.loads(doc, cls = Decoder, object_hook=data_hook)
```

As you can see I've already started the code that checks the total days, but I'm kind of confused to what to do next. Adding the sum in the dictionary is where I'm stuck.

Thanks

Comment: I don't think this works. You can't have two values with the same key in a dictionary. In this example, "days total": "100" and "days total": "48", get overwritten by "days total": "121". Hence the total is: 121+111+56+158+37+188 = 671

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to add those same values. All key values are different from the above.